# Get Images with text to center to page

Tags: html, css

Hi Im making a website for a school project and I need the images to be centered in the middle of the page  with the text below. Right now the images and text are pushed to the left side. I need the images to be centered in the page and spread out, with the text still below.

HTML

```
<section class="middle">

        <div class="rowone">
            <img src="images/logofootball.png" height="200" width="200">
            <div class="text">Text</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rowone">
            <img src="images/logofootball.png" height="200" width="200">
            <div class="text">Text</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rowone">
            <img src="images/logofootball.png" height="200" width="200">
            <div class="text">Text</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rowone">
            <img src="images/logofootball.png" height="200" width="200">
            <div class="text">Text</div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

CSS

```
.middle {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.rowone {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 1% 1% 45px 1%;
}

.text {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    margin: 30px;
    background-color: gray;
}

.rowone img {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick.

HTML

```
    <section class="middle">
<center>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
        <div class="rowone">
            <img src="images/logofootball.png" height="200" width="200">
            <div class="text">Text</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rowone">
            <img src="images/logofootball.png" height="200" width="200">
            <div class="text">Text</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rowone">
            <img src="images/logofootball.png" height="200" width="200">
            <div class="text">Text</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rowone">
            <img src="images/logofootball.png" height="200" width="200">
            <div class="text">Text</div>
        </div>
  </center>
    </section>
```

CSS

```
.middle {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.rowone {
  padding-left: 100px;
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 1% 1% 45px 1%;
}

.text {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    margin: 30px;
    background-color: gray;
}

.rowone img {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at following example. This can be comfortable solution for you. Image and Text are wrapped by **.wrapper** and
**flex: 1;** basically says, that all wrapper elements should have the same size within **.rowone** .

```css
.middle {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.rowone {
  display: flex;
}

.wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  max-height: 200px;
  flex: 1;
}

.text {
  background-color: gray;
}

img {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<section class="middle">
  <div class="rowone">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
      <div class="text">Text</div>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
      <div class="text">Text</div>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
      <div class="text">Text</div>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
      <div class="text">Text</div>
    </div>
  </div>

</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to learn and use [CSS Flex Container](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox_container.asp)

Now your parent container *.middle* will look like this:

```
.middle{
   display: flex; // this will help you align your elements.
   justify-content: center; // with the center value, it will align your items at the center of your parent container.
   align-items: center; // and this will align your items in the middle of the parent container which is what you're trying  to achieve.
}
```

and you should leave out the **float: left** on your *.rowone* items. This is what makes your items be pushed on to the left side of the container.

Answer (score 0):

I have used flex to spread out the images. I think it is the best way to divide a section into columns.
And a simple text align center for centered text.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0h97gtp6/2/)

HTML

```
<section class="middle">
    <div class="rowone">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200" height="200" width="200">
        <div class="text">Text</div>
    </div>
    <div class="rowone">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200" height="200" width="200">
        <div class="text">Text</div>
    </div>
    <div class="rowone">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200" height="200" width="200">
        <div class="text">Text</div>
    </div>
    <div class="rowone">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200" height="200" width="200">
        <div class="text">Text</div>
    </div>
</section>
```

CSS

```
.middle {
    /*position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;*/
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.rowone {
    /*float: left;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 1% 1% 45px 1%;*/
    text-align: center;
}

.text {
    /*position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    margin: 30px;*/
    background-color: gray;
    display:inline-block;
}

.rowone img {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
```